# What does 'stale file handle' in Linux mean?

Tags: linux, unix

Say I have a terminal open, and through that terminal I have `cd`'ed to some directory. Through another terminal, I delete that directory and restore it back from an identical backup. When I try to `vim` a file from the first terminal, in the same directory, why do I get an error about a stale file handle? What does it mean? (On a side note, I have found that it is possible to bypass this issue through `cd $(pwd)`.)

Comment: If you NFS mount a directory (name it adir) from host A to host B, then do the delete-and-restore thing for adir on host A, you can also get the error "Stale file handle" when you access adir on host B. Use the command `touch` on host A can make it normal.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

When the directory is deleted, the [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) for that directory (and the inodes for its contents) are recycled.  The pointer your shell has to that directory's inode (and its contents's inodes) are now no longer valid.  When the directory is restored from backup, the old inodes are *not* (necessarily) reused; the directory and its contents are stored on random inodes.  The only thing that stays the same is that the *parent* directory reuses the same name for the restored directory (because you told it to).

Now if you attempt to access the contents of the directory that your original shell is still pointing to, it communicates that request to the file system as a request for the original inode, which has since been recycled (and may even be in use for something entirely different now).  So you get a `stale file handle` message because you asked for some nonexistent data.

When you perform a `cd` operation, the shell reevaluates the inode location of whatever destination you give it.  Now that your shell knows the new inode for the directory (and the new inodes for its contents), future requests for its contents will be valid.

Comment: Ah, so  this is just the system's way of treating invalid/null inode pointers?

Comment: Yes.  I don't know enough about the details to know what would happen if, for example, you tried to reference an inode that had already been recycled to point at something else.  Would you still get a stale file handle?  Or would you get unexpected data?

Comment: I don't think the system would reuse it since someone is actually using that I-node by having it as the current directory.

Comment: Actually, I could cd, but once inside `ls` gave me the stale file handle. It is not restored