# Node js Error in exceptions log

Tags: linux, ubuntu, node.js

I'm getting this error in exceptions.log file in node server. Could someone please explain what is this issue? we are using React JS v16.8.6, Node JS v8.14.0 running on Ubuntu v16.04 and we are doing a server side rendering.

```
 error:
   { Error: Unknown system error -116: Unknown system error -116, write
     errno: -116,
     code: 'Unknown system error -116',
     syscall: 'write' },
  level: 'error',
  message: 'uncaughtException: Unknown system error -116: Unknown system error -116, write\nError: Unknown system error -116: Unknown system error -116, write',
  stack: 'Error: Unknown system error -116: Unknown system error -116, write',
  exception: true,
  date: 'Sat Jun 29 2019 19:52:25 GMT+0530 (IST)',
  process:
   { pid: 127,
     uid: 0,
     gid: 0,
     cwd: '/opt/maatran',
     execPath: '/usr/bin/node',
     version: 'v8.14.0',
     argv:
      [ '/usr/bin/node',
        '/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainer.js',
        'start',
        'ecosystem.config.js' ],
     memoryUsage:
      { rss: 184356864,
        heapTotal: 154181632,
        heapUsed: 138251728,
        external: 929873 } },
  os:
   { loadavg: [ 0.279296875, 0.14697265625, 0.099609375 ],
     uptime: 326785 },
  trace: [],
  timestamp: '2019-06-29T14:22:25.457Z' }
```

Thanks for the help. Please let me know if anyone needs more information.

Answer (score 2):

Very partial answer:

Error `-116` is "stale file handle", as you can find for example if you go through the `errno.h` header files on your system.

This happens in a `write` syscall, as the error message says.

For details about "stale file handle", see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105260/what-does-stale-file-handle-in-linux-mean).

So you need to figure out on which file that happens and what directory etc. gets deleted beforehand so you end up in a situation where you get this error message. The usual way to do this is to add debugging messages to your code, until you have enough information to track the problem down. (This kind of debugging is impossible to do remotely by Q&A on this site).